# OWASP ESAPI can't find my ESAPI.properties file although it exists in directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, owasp, esapi

I have problems configuring ESAPI to let it work with my Spring Boot Web Application (maven project).

I'm using this URL for help : https://web.archive.org/web/20161005210258/http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java

And from this URL I have chosen this part to put ESAPI.properties in a specific directory :

> The reference {@code SecurityConfiguration} manages all the settings used by the ESAPI in a single place. In this reference
>    * implementation, resources can be put in several locations, which are searched in the following order:
>    *
>
> * 1) Inside a directory set with a call to SecurityConfiguration.setResourceDirectory( "C:\temp\resources" ).
>    *

So for that here is my code :

1 - In **application.properties** :

esapi.path=/data/folder/testApp/Apps/MyApp/ESAPIConf

2 - In **StartupApplication.java** (class that will be executed only once at the startup of my application) :

```
@Component
public class StartupApplication implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        new GlobalVars();

        GlobalVars.esapiPropertyFilePath = env.getProperty("esapi.path");
        // this setResourceDirectory to be executed once
        ESAPI.securityConfiguration().setResourceDirectory(GlobalVars.esapiPropertyFilePath);

...etc

}
```

3 - In my **jsp page** :

```
<form action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="linkVariabletoDBFields()">

<input type="hidden" name = "nameconf" id="nameconf" value="<%=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute(request.getParameter("confname")) %>" />
```

**The Problem :**

When the application server (JBOSS EAP 7.2) is starting and more specifically when StartupApplication class is executed the **setResourceDirectory** is returning :

```
ESAPI: Reset resource directory to: /data/folder/testApp/Apps/MyApp/ESAPIConf
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
ESAPI: Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /home/linuxuser/ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: /data/folder/testApp/Apps/MyApp/ESAPIConf/ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Not found in 'user.home' (/home/linuxuser) directory: /home/linuxuser/esapi/ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Loading ESAPI.properties via file I/O failed. Exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
ESAPI: SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using current thread context class loader!
ESAPI: SecurityConfiguration for Validator.ConfigurationFile.MultiValued not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
ESAPI: Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /home/linuxuser/validation.properties
ESAPI: Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: /data/folder/testApp/Apps/MyApp/ESAPIConf/validation.properties
ESAPI: Not found in 'user.home' (/home/linuxuser) directory: /home/linuxuser/esapi/validation.properties
ESAPI: Loading validation.properties via file I/O failed.
ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties via the classpath.
ESAPI: SUCCESSFULLY LOADED validation.properties via the CLASSPATH from 'esapi/' using current thread context class loader!
```

It cannot find the properties file although the file exists in **/data/folder/testApp/Apps/MyApp/ESAPIConf**

And when I access my jsp page I'm getting :

```
Error :  org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
```

I guess because the ESAPI.properties was not found.

Kindly help.

Comment: Does your app have the appropriate argument with which to find the properties file in a nonstandard location?

Comment: And what are the file permissions?

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else.  Note the line:  `ESAPI: SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using current thread context class loader!`

Comment: If you read the URL mentioned above you will find that ESAPI will try to search in different locations. Although my files are put in the '/data/folder/testApp/Apps/MyApp/ESAPIConf' having the permissions rw-rw-rw and having the same user that is running Jboss and same group

Comment: What happens when you try `data/folder/testApp/Apps/MyApp/ESAPIConf`

Comment: ESAPI: Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: /data/folder/testApp/Apps/MyApp/ESAPIConf/ESAPI.properties

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then Maven>Update Project
This solved it for me.
Weird thing is I never added this dependency before this problem cropped up and yet the ESAPI worked well.